# groupby and drop groups if the sender is not in the list of receiver list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have exchange data. A transaction initiator sends USD and will receive Euro in return. I want to make sure that each transaction contains the correct information about the initiator. The way to ensure that is that the one who is sending money to the exchange always appear in `to` as well within the same transaction.

```
transaction  from      to      currency
1             A    exchange      USD
1          exchange    A         Euro
1             B        C         Euro
2             C    exchange      USD
2             B        D         Euro
2             A        G         Euro
3             F    exchange      USD
3             D        A         Euro
3             B        F         Euro
4             R    exchange      USD
4             A        D         Euro
4             B        Q         Euro
```

Desired df

```
transaction  from      to      currency
1             A    exchange      USD
1          exchange    A         Euro
3             F    exchange      USD
3             B        F         Euro
```

Here, for each transaction, the initiator is `A`, `C`, `F`, and `R`. But for `C`, `R`, there is no record of incoming transactions. So I want to exclude these transactions.

Comment: "But for C, R, there is no record " - there is record for `C`: `B        C         Euro` . So you want only `R` to be excluded?

Comment: Also, should the checks be done per ID independently?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you are right. I edited the post. mozway only per sender ID (to exchange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function to find *sent* and *back* transactions (for exchange):

```
def f(df_):
    m1 = df_['to'].eq('exchange')  # find sender
    from_ = df_[m1]['from'].values
    m2 = df_['to'].isin(from_)  # check if sender appears as receiver
    if not m2.sum():  # no incoming/back transaction
        return None
    return df_[m1 | m2]

df = df.groupby('transaction').apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
   transaction      from        to currency
0            1         A  exchange      USD
1            1  exchange         A     Euro
2            3         F  exchange      USD
3            3         B         F     Euro
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to filter the groups for which each from ID with "exchange" in To is also present in To:

```
(df.groupby('transaction')
   .filter(lambda g: set(g.loc[g['to'].eq('exchange'), 'from'])
                    .intersection(g['to'])>set())
)
```

Output:

```
   transaction      from        to currency
0            1         A  exchange      USD
1            1  exchange         A     Euro
2            1         B         C     Euro
6            3         F  exchange      USD
7            3         D         A     Euro
8            3         B         F     Euro
```

If you want to match across transaction IDs:

```
m  = df['to'].eq('exchange')
df.loc[((df['from'].isin(set(df.loc[m, 'from']).intersection(df['to'])) & m )
        .groupby(df['transaction']).transform('any')
       )]
```

Output:

```
   transaction      from        to currency
0            1         A  exchange      USD
1            1  exchange         A     Euro
2            1         B         C     Euro
3            2         C  exchange      USD # match in transaction 1
4            2         B         D     Euro
5            2         A         G     Euro
6            3         F  exchange      USD
7            3         D         A     Euro
8            3         B         F     Euro
```

Comment: Hi, i edited the question. I want to keep only groups where the sender also appears in the receiver in `euro` rows, but also only keep the corresponding rows where the receiver info is in.